# Sublime text pink highlighting of .py files

Tags: python, sublimetext

Whenever I open odoo project or sometime django project, all the .py files began to get highlighted in the colour pink and I don't know the reason why. Sometimes I had to set syntax to python by hitting Ctrl + Shift + P and it turns alright. but, I can't do the same for each and every files right ? tough I do that, If I close and open the project still the same exists. Please, someone do help me out to get rid of this. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: If manually setting the syntax to Python solves your problem, then something has happened to make Sublime think that these files are not python. To fix that, while you have one of these files open, select `View > Syntax > Open all with current extension as > Python` to tell Sublime that from now on it should consider these files Python files.

Comment: Superb! Thanks a ton man :) It actually worked.!

Answer (score 3):

Check if you set the **proper type** of file on the right down corner:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could come from an invalid syntax... your code does not look like python code...